# uninstall sql express which is not show in add/remove program list

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-express

my question is simple , i want to uninstall sql express 2005 which is removed half and now not showing in add remove program list, it is not allowing me to install new one as well i am not able to remove it , i am stuck please help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your installation folder and run command prompt in that location and type

```
start /wait setup.exe /qb REMOVE=ALL INSTANCENAME=MSSQLSERVER
```

Answer (score 0):

The year is 2023 and I just had the same problem.
I followed the instructions here, which was incredibly helpful: [Install/Uninstall SQL Server Via Command](https://peter-whyte.com/install-sql-server-via-command/)

Unfourtunately the last step wasn't working... ...but the principle was.

1. Go to your setup folder, in my case: "SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU"
   You'll know it's the right one if it has a SETUP.EXE file in it.
2. Create a shortcut to the installer. Bear with me.
3. Right-click into Properties of your newly created shortcut and under the Target section (In the Shortcut tab) assuming you are seeing `...SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU\SETUP.EXE` or `"...SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU\SETUP.EXE"`
4. Append the following to the target:  `/ACTION=Uninstall`

So it now looks like: `...SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU\SETUP.EXE  /ACTION=Uninstall` or `"...SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU\SETUP.EXE" /ACTION=Uninstall`